# "in total" or just "total"?

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the correct way to write the following sentence about the total goals scored during his career?

"Scored 100 goals total" or "Scored 100 goals **in** total"?

Comment: There are many ways to say this but your first one is not one of them.

Comment: The preposition ***in*** is *sometimes* omitted by native speakers in your cited context, but it would nearly always be included in *written* text. Note that "Scored 100 goals in total" isn't actually a sentence, because it's got no *subject*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In total**, it should be -though it's not the only way.

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-total): 'If there are a number of things in total, there are that number when you count or add them all together'.

'The player scored a hundred goals in total' is correct. However, the prior in your question is not.

Comment: Does this rule apply everywhere? For example is the following sentence correct: "typed 5000 words in total"? Or should it be: "typed 5000 words total"?

Comment: @FurtJunk yes, it is a general rule.

Comment: While "in total" is more natural, nobody's going to have trouble understanding either.